# Openpyxl: How to resolve .iter_cols unsupported operand error

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I'm having an issue retrieving the cell values of multiple columns in specific rows from two different worksheets. I'm attempting to iterate through the first column of two worksheets, which hold unordered key values. Once I iterate through all key values and find the cell location of the matching values in the two worksheets, I call my def column_name function to iterate through a range of columns for that specific key value(the row cell is passed as a parameter into my function; indicated by **uniqueID**). [m1 and worksh1] and [m2 and worksh2] represent sheets in the workbook. If anyone can help me resolve the following error, I'd greatly appreciate it. This error appears on the first line of my column_name function.
`for col_cells in workbk1.iter_cols(min_row=uniqueID,max_row=uniqueID,min_col=start,max_col=last):`

**Error:** >File C:...\Python39\site-packages...openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py, line 516, in _cells_by_col for row in range(min_row, max_row+1). TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Cell' and 'int'

```
 
def column_name(workbk1, workbk2, uniqueID):
 for col_cells in workbk1.iter_cols(min_row=uniqueID,max_row=uniqueID,min_col=start,max_col=last):
       for cell in col_cells:
            for col_cells2 in workbk2.iter_cols(min_row=uniqueID,max_row=uniqueID,min_col=start2,max_col=last2):
                 for cell2 in col_cells2:
                    [execute code]
```

Comment: Please show the entire traceback.  We can't tell which of your code lines caused this.  Where did "start" and "end" come from?

Comment: Thank you Tim! I edited my OP with the full traceback and more code. 'start' and 'end' is the column indices for the column range I'd like to iterate through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `column_name` function the last argument is `uniqueID` which is passed to `min_row` and `max_row`. It means that the `unqiueID` should be an integer. But when calling the function, it is being called as `column_name(m1,m2,cell)` where we are passing the actual `cell` object as `uniqueID`.

Later in openpyxl when it tries `max_row+1`, it fails with following error because `max_row` is actually a `Cell`:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Cell' and 'int'
```

Comment: Ah I see the issue now. Thank you for pointing that out! Can this be resolved by replacing cell with  `column_name(m1,m2,cell.row)` instead to get the integer value of the row index? Or do you know of another solution?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't analyzed the code so deeply such that what `uniqueId` is or should be etc. I have just pointed out the error so you can move forward.